# Tizen Emulator not playing video

Tags: tizen-emulator

I am trying to run a html5 app on tizen smart tv emulator 2.4. The mp4 vidfeo plays perfectly fine on web simulator but not on emulator. I don't have a tv right now to test it. Is this a problem with the emulator? Can I submit the app without testing on actual tv assuming there is no problem with the video?

Answer (score 5):

If the case is the source of your mp4 video is web, then consider the answer.

Web Simulator uses your PC's network configuration (network configuration of google chrome). To access internet from TV emulator you have to give permissions.

Add internet access privilege for your Tizen application in the config.xml file.Internet Privilege allows the application to access the Internet.

```
<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

Also defining external access Policy may be required to access network. According to the W3C Access Requests Policy (WARP), you cannot access external network resources by default. If you require access to an external network resource, you must request network resource permissions for the Web application using the Policy in the config.xml file.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/> <!--For any url--> 
Or
<access origin="your url here" subdomains="true"/> <!--For Specific url-->
<access origin="your url 2 here" subdomains="true"/>
```

Now your application should be able to access the internet from the emulator as well as real devices.

If you are still having issue I would suggest to post in Samsung D Forum. Community-> Tizen TV

https://www.samsungdforum.com/

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in the simulator, it should also work in the emulator.  However, I sometimes find the emulator is a little flakey when it comes to video and would always recommend testing an app on an actual device.

You can still submit the app.  If the video fails during QA, they will reject it, but you can fix it and resubmit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but a little different. I can to play on the emulator but some videos required a lot of time to start to play. For example [this](https://playtime.tubemogul.com/ad_promoted_videos/c6058f7d-dbd5-4d08-8dcf-16f82b0a97d2.mp4). I tested using AVplay, NaCl and VideoJS and either required at least 30seg to start. I tough that could be the size (i used other bigger and play normally) or the server (I moved the video to other place and fails anyway). In fact I have a set of videos with same behavior on samsung devices or samsung emulator.